# ArcGIS Error: Cannot set input into parameter spatial_reference

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.
I can do "add XY data as layer" to associate latitude and longitude to a .dbf table, but when I try to do the same with python script it gives me an error:

```
Python code:
import arcgisscripting, sys, string, os
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
in_Table = "F:\Otim\interf\cg_rea.dbf"
in_x = "Latitude"
in_y = "Longitude"
out_Layer = "cg_rea_otim"
spref = "Coordinate Systems\Projected CoordinateSystems\Lisboa_Hayford_Gauss_IGeoE.prj"
gp.MakeXYEventLayer(in_Table, in_x, in_y, out_Layer, spref) #line where is the error!
```

Error: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 191, in  ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Make XY Event Layer). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter spatial_reference.

Comment: Maybe try using the full path to the .prj file?

Comment: You should use arcpy.SpatialReference(code of projection) to set the spatial reference variable

Comment: How I can do this? @MacroZED

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have ArcGIS 10.2, it would be better to use ArcPy. 
The reference system you have mentioned is http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/lisboa-hayford-gauss-igeoe/ with the code 102164.

Therefore try the following:

```
import arcpy, sys, string, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"path\to\work\area"

in_Table = r"F:\Otim\interf\cg_rea.dbf"
in_x = "Longitude"
in_y = "Latitude"
out_Layer = "cg_rea_otim"
spref =  arcpy.SpatialReference(102164) 
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, in_x, in_y, out_Layer, spref)
```

Comment: I tryed this @MacroZED but it gives me other error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 202, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MakeXYEventLayer'

Comment: sorry, the actual tool is arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management. Ive edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: Now it runs without problems but show values on a wrong place on map...

Comment: What format are you lats and longs in the DBF? They must be in Decimal Degrees in order for the MakeXYEvent tool to work.

Comment: Yes I have in Decimal Degrees, and when I did manually, usinf File->Add data->Add XY Data it worked, but now, using python, it puts values on a different place..

Comment: I see where its gone wrong. Y = Latitude and X = Longitude

Comment: If I have coordinates at degrees, at Projected Coordinate System: Lisboa_Hayford_Gauss_IGeoE , how can I convert to decimal in order to use this function? @MacroZED

Comment: you need to convert to a geographic system to get decimal degrees. If its a projected system, it shouldnt be in degrees,

Comment: Using the same code I applied to another table and I have another error: 
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 342, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6381, in MakeXYEventLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000212: Cannot create XY event source Failed to execute (MakeXYEventLayer).  What is wrong?